# Wanting to remove multi stores and go back to single store view scope in Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, multistore, store-view, multi-website

Is it possible to switch our store back to single store mode? Is this possible now? It says,

> "This setting will not be taken into account if system has more than
> one store view."

We have two stores on Magento2.3.5. However, we are wanting to remove one of these stores and its views from admin, since we never use it. No products and not much data has been saved on the other store view. However, switching to single store mode in does not do anything and I take it because it still sees the other store views so it does not take that setting into account.

Would I have to remove 2nd stores website? I did not see an option to remove store. How do I remove 2nd store?

[image]

Comment: create a backup of your database and remove your extra store after that you can use single store mode

Comment: Thank you @dh darvishani for the quick response, where can I remove the second store from? I see in 'All Store Views' I can remove 2nd stores website. Is this how I would remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create database backup then go to below path in admin panel.

Stores -> Setting -> All Stores

here remove your website,store and store view which is not required.
Note: please do not delete main website, main store and main store view.

after that you can switch to "single store mode".

Answer (score 1):

- Backup Database

  php bin/magento setup:backup --db

This command line will backup current database and save to a static file. It will be stored to ./var/backups/ folder.

Then follow below steps

- Step 1: Login to your Magento 2 backend

  On the Admin sidebar, click Stores. Then under Settings, select Configuration.
  In the panel on the left under General, select General.
- Step 2: Set up Single-Store mode

  Scroll down to the bottom of the page, and expand the Single Store Mode section.
  Set Enable Single Store Mode to “Yes.”
- Step 3: Save the configuration

  Click Save Config.
  When prompting to refresh the cache, do the following:
  Click the Cache Management link in the system message at the top of the page
  Mark the Page Cache checkbox.
  With Actions set to “Refresh,” click Submit.

Comment: Magento abandoned its backup tools and recommends just taking a dump. So do this instead: mysqldump -u username -p database > backup-name.sql